# Process the output of python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to make a system call in Python and store the output to a string so that I can process it in my Python program.To be more specific of what i am doing this a part of my code

```
r = subprocess.Popen(['c:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe', '-c', 'fuser somethingsomething'] , stdout=subprocess.PIPE )
output, errs = r.communicate()
```

How can i manipulate/save the output so that i can for example kill the process(if exists) fuser returns?I have tried to use `decode('utf-8')`  but i haven't succeed so far.

**EDIT**

I replaced `popen` with `check_output` removed `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` and i got the output i wanted with `output = r.decode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question some weeks back, and finaly came up with this :

```
pids = []
with subprocess.Popen('tasklist | findstr /i "<your process name>"', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True) as p:
    for line in p.stdout:
        pids.append([elem for elem in line.split() if elem != ''][1])

for pid in pids:
    subprocess.call('taskkill /f /pid ' + pid, shell=True)
```

Maybe it can be applied to your problem.